# how to list processed files by Add-NTFSAccess

Tags: powershell

I am new in Powershell and i have a question : i'm using this command line to apply rights, which works perfectly :

```
import-module NtfsSecurity

$Adminfilesserver = "Domain\Admins"

$Path1 = "\\server\data"

Add-NTFSAccess -AccessRights FullControl -Account ($Adminfilesserver) -Path $Path1 -AccessType Allow -AppliesTo ThisFolderSubfoldersAndFiles -Verbose
```

-Verbose doesn't give me which files are processed by the command line if DATA already exists with files in it... Can someone tell me how can I proceed plz ? Thx. (sorry for the format, i've not been able to do it correctly)

Comment: where are you getting `Add-NTFSAccess`? that cmdlet does not appear to be in any of the standard modules.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Sorry I forgot to mention : import-module NtfsSecurity

Comment: @Pax212fr - PLEASE, add that info your your Question. it is needed to make sense of your code. [*grin*]

Comment: Can anyone show me the way plz ? Thx

Comment: i don't use that module, so i cannot give you any definite Answer. [*sigh ...*] however, i would start by examining **_all_** the parameters for that cmdlet. if that doesn't help, then you may need to do a before/after comparison to determine what changed.